# Session start event handler in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, session, jakarta-ee

In asp.net, we have Global.asax, we have session_start method, runs when new user first visit.
is that similar thing in jsp?

I got advice i can use Intercepter, but i still confuse that, how intercepter capture the session_start

Answer (score 3):

Use a [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html), which is an *interface for receiving notification events about HttpSession lifecycle changes.*

Override its [sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionCreated%28javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent%29) method. Sample code :

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

  /**
  * Receives notification that a session has been created.
  */
  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
       HttpSession session = se.getSession(); \\ handle to HttpSession Object
   System.out.println("sessionCreated");
  }

  /**
  * Receives notification that a session is about to be invalidated.
  */
  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {

  } 
}
```

Add the listener class to your Deployment Descriptor `web.xml` :

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>SessionListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

As @Luiggi pointed out if you are using `Servlet 3.0` complaint Container like `Tomcat 7`, you can just define the listener class with [@WebListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html) annotation instead of declaring the listener in `web.xml`, though I prefer the orthodox approach because you can find all the listener information(except *binding listeners*) in one file itself.

Comment: Note that if OP's using a Servlet 3.0 featured web application server like Tomcat 7, he could get rid of the `<listener>` configuration in *web.xml* and just add the `@WebListener` annotation in the `@SessionListener` class.

Answer (score 1):

create a listener and add it in web.xml like this

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>sessionMaintainance.sessionMaintain</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

a listener is a class that implements HttpSessionListener. it has two methods sessionCreated and sessionDestroyed. when you want anything to do when session is created than write it in sessionCreated method and when you want to do something when session is destroyed then do that in sessionDestroyed method